# Calling function to return private variable from class not working

Tags: c++

So I am making a small game in C++ and I have run across a problem. I have a class called player inside my player.h file, and inside this class I have a public function called `getPotion()`. I also have a private static variable called `potion`. I have the exact same thing for the players health, and the `getHealth()` function returns the private static int `playerHealth` perfectly. But for apparently no reason, the `getPotion` function doesn't return the potion. I get an error instead. I've also included the header file in all my other files.

Here's the code:

(Sorry, I don't know how to insert code, so I have to write it out)

**player.h** (the code that I'm having trouble with):

```
class Player{
private:
    static int potions;

public:
    int getPotions();
}
```

**player.cpp** (again the code I have trouble with):

```
int Player::potions;

int Player::getPotions(){
    Player player;
    return player.potions;
}
```

I have probably left out some bits of code like return and such, but that's because I have a small amount of time to ask this question, so I put the parts that related to my problem.

Comment: Why do you create a new `Player` in the `getPotions` function? Whatever thought process led you to think that was something sensible to do needs to be re-examined.

Comment: Also, you almost certainly **don't** want `potions` to be declared `static`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Exactly. If there were two `Player`s, each would need their own count of the number of potions they have. So it should *not* be static.

Comment: Ok, Ive changed it so its not static anymore, but how do I call it now?

Comment: Call what? Did you see my answer?

Comment: crud yep I see it now, sorry I didnt refresh haha silly me.

Comment: When asking about something that does not compile, you should provide the compiler error and line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you are trying to return a `static` member of a class as if it were instantiated member of the object. Static members are referred to by `Class::member`, not `object.member`.

Second, I don't think you want `potions` to be static. Static members are shared between all objects of the class. So if player A has 100 health potions, then player B would have the same 100 health potions.

Third, you declare `Player::potions` at the top of your `.cpp` file. I don't think that's what you want. The `potions` member was already declared in your `.h` file.

player.h:

```
class Player
{
    private:
        int potions;

    public:
        int getPotions();
};
```

player.cpp:

```
int Player::getPotions()
{
    return potions;
}
```

If you DID want `potions` to be static, then change it to:

```
return Player::potions;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
Player player;
return player.potions;
```

to simply

```
return potions;
```

You're creating a new player and returning *that* object's potions, not the potions of the "this" object.

Comment: `potions` is static. The way his class is designed, instances don't have potions.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts, yep this needs to be fixed as well.  My oversight.